# Can you run a Ubuntu 20.04 docker image on a Ubuntu 22.04 host?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Can you run a docker image that was built using a different version of Ubuntu? Ex, image is 20.04, host is 22.04.

Comment: Yes, it's what it's meant for. You can even run a Ubuntu 23.04 on a 22.04 host or even an older Ubuntu version like 16.04.

Comment: Yes, definitely. That is the whole point of docker. It will even run on a Fedora or Arch host. The only thing to consider is hardware platform; if the image is built for x86_64, it will not run on arm.

Comment: Does kernel version impact it though?

Comment: Impact what exactly? There might be some random tool in Ubuntu 20.04 which might be tightly coupled to the kernel version and won't work with newer versions, but this site isn't the place to predict what will and won't work for you. Just run it and if you then get an actual problem, ask about that.